# Alamofire timeout not working when larger than 60 seconds

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

In my project, I use `Alamofire` to send a `POST` request, the code looks like this:

```
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url as! String)!)
    request.httpMethod = method.rawValue
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters)
    request.timeoutInterval = 120

    let alamofireRequest = Alamofire.request(request)

    alamofireRequest.responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in
             // do somthing
    }
```

when I set the `timeoutInterval` to 10, it works well. But, when I set it to 120, after about 60 second I receive a timeout error from sever.

Does iOS has any default setting for the timeout property? It can't be lager than 60?

Where I can find some documentations for it?
Hope anyone can give me some suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the `timeoutInterval` in Alamofire won't change the server's `timoutInterval`.
Server responds according to its own configuration.
But if you need, you can change the timeout on the server side by modifying the API.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will connect to the server side.

Comment: I have already asked the server side about this, but they didn't set the `timeoutInterval`. Is there has any other possibility?

Comment: Even if they didn't set the timeout interval, there is a default timeout interval for a session in configuration. Can you tell me more about your server so that I can help you better.

Comment: Oh, I get it. The server wrote by another company, so I don't know the details either. I'll tell them try to change the configuration, thank you very much

Comment: I connected another server which wrote by my team leader, and the timeout interval works correctly, so I think it's must be the server's mistake. Thanks for your help.